# Debugging divs and the box model

Tags: html, css

Is there a browser plug-in I can use to help me determine why my  tags and css styles don't render the way I expect them to?

It would be really great if I could browse to my test page, and activate a plug in that would show me the dimensions and location of each div box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Google Chrome, the built-in developer tools are very good.  Just right-click on the part of your page you would like to debug and choose "Inspect Element" and the developer tool pane will appear with the selected part of the page highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at excellent firefox addon:

[FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/)

[image]

Comment: @Aheho: Yes it is internet explorer toolbar but i don't think it is as versatile as firebug. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

use firebug, it's very simple and also good.